# Membership & Event Registration/Management plus-ins for non-profit

Tags: plugin-recommendation, user-registration, events, membership

I maintain the website for a non-profit organization for historians/archivists. I'm migrating a static HTML site to WP. One of the main reasons for the transition is to utilize plugins for membership mgmt. and event registration. The free plugins in both these areas have not been all that user-friendly, so I'm looking for recommendations for plugins that achieve these goals. I need PayPal integration, not so sure about credit card transactions. One main problem I have in selecting a free/premium membership plugin is that I'm not trying to create premium content or a firewall. Our members haven't expressed in features such as: forums, member directories, etc.), so I'm really looking for a plugin(s) which let me and event planners facilitate event registration & mgmt., and creation/renewal of memberships & paying dues.

I've looked at Event Espresso, S2Member, WP-Member, Magic Members, and played with all the free plugins. If I'm going to write a request for funds to purchase premium plugins to make these tasks easier, what plugins have any of you had success with?

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I am a front-end developer working full time with Event Espresso.  This is by far the most flexible, feature rich platform if you want to work exclusively with WP without using an external booking manager.  Its relatively easy to develop for.

Comment: Thanks. I like Event Espresso but can't seem to find any info. about what membership plugins can be integrated. Can you build your own membership system with custom content types, or do some existing plugins work better for this?

Comment: I have figured out that a lot of premium & free membership plugins work off the "wp_users" database table. Making it a bit easier to understand how integration with EE works.